# Negation of $\exists a \in \Bbb R$ such that $a >0$ and $\forall x \in \Bbb R$; if $x \ge a$, then $2^{-x} < \frac{1}{50}$.

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

To negate the following statement:

> $\exists a \in \Bbb R$ such that $a >0$ and $\forall x \in \Bbb R$; if $x \ge a$, then $2^{-x} < \frac{1}{50}$.

Note that for negation we do the following:

"A and B" changes to "not A or not B".

"if A, then B" changes to   "A and not B".

"For all $x, A(x)$" changes to "There exist $x$ such that not $A(x)$".

"There exists $x$ such that $A(x)$" changes to   "For every $x$, not $A(x)$".

---

So my result after negating the given statement is:

$\forall a \in \Bbb R; a \le 0$ or $\exists x \in \Bbb R$, $x \ge a$ and $2^{-x} \ge \frac{1}{50}$.

---

Is the negation of the given statement correct?

Thank You.

Comment: It must be: $\forall x \in \mathbb R; a > 0 \ldots$.

Comment: Unwind the "restricted" quantifiers... "$\exists x \text { such that } a > 0 \text { and } \ldots$" is $\exists x [(a > 0) \land \ldots]$ and as you say the negation of $(P \land Q)$ is $\lnot (P \to Q)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so the negation will be: $\forall a \in \Bbb R; a > 0$, $\exists x \in \Bbb R$, $x \ge a$ and $2^{-x} \ge \frac{1}{50}$.

Comment: Yes...........................

Comment: Yours is correct, and it is equivalent to the one others are telling you

Comment: The simplest way to avoid misunderstanding (see some comments and answer) is to put the negation sign in front: $\lnot [\exists x \in \mathbb R \ldots]$ and move it inside step-by-step. The other "trick" is to unwind the restricted quantifiers: $(\exists x : P(x)) Q(x)$ is $\exists x [P(x) \land Q(x)]$ while $(\forall x : P(x))Q(x)$ is $\forall x [P(x) \to Q(x)]$.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall a \in \mathbb{R} \text{ with } a > 0 \exists x \in \mathbb{R}: x \geq a \text{ and } 2^{-x} \geq 1/50$.

Answer (score 0):

First write the statement formally (changing restricted quantifiers to implications):

$$\exists a \in \Bbb R: (a >0) \land \left( \forall x \in \Bbb R: (x \ge a) \to (2^{-x} < \frac{1}{50})\right)$$

The negation of the implication is

$$(x \ge a) \land (2^{-x} \ge \frac{1}{50})$$ as the only way to make an implication false is to make the antecedent true and the consequent false.

So the negation of the statement between braces, with the quantor, is

$$\exists x \in \Bbb R: (x \ge a) \land (2^{-x} \ge \frac{1}{50})$$

So the negation of the $\land$-statement is the $\lor$ of the negations so

$$(a \le 0) \lor \left( \exists x \in \Bbb R: (x \ge a) \land (2^{-x} \ge \frac{1}{50}) \right)$$

and taking care of the outer quantifier:

$$\forall a \in \Bbb R: (a \le 0) \lor \left( \exists x \in \Bbb R: (x \ge a) \land (2^{-x} \ge \frac{1}{50}) \right)$$

which is the negation of the original statement.

This seems to match yours.

If you think about it, the statement is trivial for $a \le 0$, so we see this last statement is equivalent to

$$\forall a >0:  \exists x \in \Bbb R: (x \ge a) \land (2^{-x} \ge \frac{1}{50}) $$